# Delay when loading images - Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I retrieve my images from a URL and display it to the user. Sometimes their is a delay displaying these images. For example the page loads the user sees the description text but after a few secs the image pops up. This does not always happens. I want the loading control to keep loading while the image is retrieved and not stop before. I use this code to retrieve and display the images.

```
 string url = "google/images"
               Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
               IMG.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in windows Phone you need to keep UI active else it crashes. What I would suggest is either you show a default image or better an indeterminate progress ring. Once your image gets downloaded completely these will be set over the default image or the visibility of Progress Ring is set to Collapsed.

Comment: I currently have a progress bar that is displaying while the page loads.  I retrieve my links and text from a database and when i have all the data i stop the progress bar and display the information to the user. This works fine but sometimes it displays the text but after a while it displays the image.  I want the text and image always to be displayed at the same time. So even if the image requires say 20 sec extra then my loading should extend 20 secs

Comment: I am assuming you are displaying it inside a gridview. You can add Behaviours in your project and set the way in which you want to load your gridview. Check out this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/Apps/dn535964.aspx. Just set the phase of your images before text to get the required effect